# Add a new field containing a list of values to an existing JSON using jq

Tags: json, unix, jq

I would like to add a variable `IntendedFor` with values `scan1` and `scan2` to an existing JSON file.

I would like to do this with `jq` function, I tried:

```
cat existing.json | jq '.IntendedFor |= "["scan1", "scan2"]"' > output.json
```

but I get the error and and empty JSON file.

This is what i want the output.json file to look like:

```
{  "existingjsonstuff": "andsoon",  
   "IntendedFor": ["scan1", "scan2"] 
}
```

How do i get this??

Comment: If the answer below helped, you should consider reading [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `+= [..]` operator to add to the array with the elements needed.

```
jq '.IntendedFor += [ "scan1", "scan2" ]' existing.json > output.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank you! Eventually this code worked:

```
cat existing.json | jq --argjson args '["scan1","scan2"]' '.{"IntededFor"] += $args' > output.json
```